# Where should I locate Mule CRC32 filter in my flow?

Tags: mule

I want to locate Mule CRC32 calculator and filter in my flows. I've located the calculator at the end of my first flow, right before replying. But where do I locate the filter? right after receiving the second request?
When I do that I get the following error:

```
Root Exception stack trace: org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValueException: Expression Evaluator "header" with expression "invocation:crc32" returned null but a value was required.
```

Another thing that might cause this error is:
I send the first HTTP request using Firefox, then I copy the response **body** and send the second request using Postman (Chrome). Do I lose the checksum data?

Thanks,
Keren

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem here is the scope of your properties.
Looks like you want to send the header back to your requestor, that then should send it back to the server.

To do so use an oubound property at the first flow (rather than a flow variable that will never go beyond your first flow). Then if the requested send the crc back you get it as an inbound property on the second flow.

Find [here](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-school-the-mulemessage-property-scopes-and-variables/) more information about the scopes.